# Mysql limit with Group by

Tags: php, mysql

I have three tables:

1. category
2. buisness
3. business_category( having field, id, category_id, buisness_id)

One Category Belong to Many Business
and One Business can have multiple Category

Now I am trying to do this and I want to get following results:

```
Category 1

buisenn 1
buisness 2
buisnesss 3


Category 2

business 1  for cat2
business 2 for cat 2
business 3 for cat 2
```

I want to show only three business for each category.

This is the query what I tried:

```
SELECT  `category`.`name` AS `category_name`,
        `category`.`id` AS category_id,
        `business`.`avg_service_price` AS avg_price,
        `business`.`name` AS `business_name`,
        `business`.`address`,
        `business`.`address2`,
        `business`.`city`,
        `business`.`state`,
        `business`.`zipcode`,
        `business`.`id` AS `business_id`,
        `business`.`lat`,`business`.`lon` 
    FROM `business_category`
    LEFT JOIN `business`
        ON `business_category`.`business_id` = `business`.`id` 
    LEFT JOIN `category`
        ON  `business_category`.`category_id` = `category`.`id`
    GROUP BY `business`.`id`
    LIMIT 0,3
```

It show only 3 results.

Can anybody give me idea?

Thanks

Comment: Removing LIMIT 0,3 ?

Comment: it will show all results. i need 3 business form each category

Comment: It' not cleat to me what 's your expected output. I suggest you add it. But using LIMIT 0,3 will get the first three results of your query, so even if the rest your query is correct you 'll never get three business for each category

Comment: i need three business only for each category thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can not do that. Limit is used just to get the 3 rows of your query and what you want is to get all the results but just 3 elements for each category.

A solution could be, getting all the categories at first and then create a query for each category with limit 3.
Another solution could be getting all the results and then removing those that you don't want.

The first solution is slower but the second one needs more memory.

Answer (score 1):

You need the equivalent of "groupwise max".  See [my blog](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max#top_n_in_each_group), which has this example:

```
SELECT
    province, n, city, population
FROM
  ( SELECT  @prev := '', @n := 0 ) init
JOIN
  ( SELECT  @n := if(province != @prev, 1, @n + 1) AS n,
            @prev := province,
            province, city, population
        FROM  Canada
        ORDER BY
            province   ASC,
            population DESC
  ) x
WHERE  n <= 3
ORDER BY  province, n;
```